# D&D 3.5 Wizard Prestige Classes. What are the best options?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard

I'm a new D&D player (playing for a month exactly) and we're starting a new campaign at lvl 3. I undestand the basics of a wizard since I played a blaster Wiz on my first campaign, but I'm definately not an expert on building a more complex one.

Now I'm looking for a Wizard that can come up to a melee fight. I've searched and found Eldritch Knight, but I don't know how he applies in-game. My rolls are pretty good (compared to the last one) so I would love to not mess up this one. Since my race is Favored,

I've been considering to take Wiz 5, Fighter 1, and go for Eldritch Knight on the remaining levels.

Now I got some questions:

1 - When I get Fighter 1, I get proficiency with Light Armors, does it still punishes me on arcane failure %?

2 - I like the concept of using Scythes, is this an acceptable weapon or pure garbage?

3 - Is the Eldritch option good enough to not make me cry for my useless Wizard later?

4 - If there's not any good "melee" Wiz class in the game, what other prestige classes would you recommend to take a look? (feats and specialization would also be appreciated.

Thanks for the help!